# The wait operation timed out and sqlexception Timeout expired

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure-sql-database

I have weird problem with my sql azure database on the live server. The MVC controller is returning an errors as "The wait operation timed out" and Sqlexpection (0x80131904): Timeout expired".

This is happening particularly on a single a sql stored procedure. The program is that if run the stored procedure with same parameter against the database using SMSS 2012 it runs fine and returns returns in less 2 seconds.

This lets me that there is nothing wrong with my stored procedure.

I am calling the stored procedure as below.

```
List<FileFolderItem> folders = new List<FileFolderItem>();

using (DFModel db = new DFModel())
{
    folders.AddRange(
        db.GetFolderStructure(companyId, (clientid ?? companyId), folderId, currentUser.df_userId).Select(x => new FileFolderItem
        {
            Name = x.name,
            Id = x.id,
            Flags = "USER_FOLDER",
            TotalFiles = x.Files.Value,
            TotalSize = x.Size.Value
        }).ToList<FileFolderItem>()
    );

    return folders;
}
```

I have done further test by taking a backup of the database and restore on the same sql azure instance as seperate new database and pointing my application connection to the backup db and the application works.

I don't understand how should I troubleshoot this problem, there no way to restart the sql azure instance.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Edited on 13/03/2013

After further investigation - the problem seems to be with Table-Valued function (getfilesbyclaims) called from sub-procedure GetFolderTotalSize. Is this functions are not fully supported. The strange thing is that the application did go live about 4 weeks ago and this problem suddenly started yesterday @ 4pm.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFolderStructure]
    @companyid int, 
    @clientid int, 
    @folderid int, 
    @personid int
AS
SELECT 
        fd.id, 
        fd.name,        
        dbo.getfoldertotalfiles(@companyid, @clientid, fd.id, @personid) AS Files,
        --0 as Files,
        dbo.getfoldertotalsize(@companyid, @clientid, fd.id, @personid) as Size
        --0 as Size
FROM folders fd
WHERE fd.companyid = @companyid
AND fd.root_id = @folderid
AND (fd.hidden IS NULL OR fd.hidden = 0)
```

Sub-Procedure - GetFolderTotalFiles

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFolderTotalSize]
(
    @companyid int, 
    @clientid int, 
    @folderid int,
    @personid int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @size int;

    DECLARE @tblFiles TABLE (
        Id uniqueidentifier not null,
        CompanyId int,
        folderid int,
        contentLength bigint    
    );

    INSERT INTO @tblFiles(id, companyid, folderid, contentlength)
    SELECT * FROM dbo.getfilesbyclaims(@clientid, @personid);

    WITH Folder_CTE as (
    select fs.* FROM folders AS fs
    where companyid = @companyid
    AND id = @folderid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT f.* FROM folders f
    INNER JOIN Folder_CTE fcte ON fcte.id = f.root_id)

    SELECT @size = ISNULL(SUM(f.contentlength), 0) FROM folder_cte fd
    INNER JOIN @tblFiles f ON f.folderid = fd.id
    where f.companyid = @clientid

    return @size;
END

GO
```

Comment: connect to the remote server from the local application and place breakpoints around the code responsible for making the db call. what you can look for is, make sure the connection string is right, are you behind a proxy? if yes configure the remote data source to accepts connections from behind a proxy, make sure no fire wall is blocking your call to the remote datasource

Comment: This is happening on the worker role in the azure cloud service hosted on windows azure. Also changed local MVC project code to point to database and got the same error. All other db call from application have no issues except this stored proc.

Comment: i not very familiar with `azure` so cant help you in that regard

Comment: hey did u get any solution ??